# Google Recaptcha is not working on fancybox ajax popup

Tags: fancybox, recaptcha, fancybox-2

Google Recaptcha is not working on fancybox ajax generated form.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. Bellow code is working fine for me.

1. Include Google Recaptcha api js

   ```
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
   ```
2. Add Element Html

   ```
    <div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha" ></div>
   ```
3. Add Script

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("[element_id_or_class]").fancybox({
          padding     : 0,
          maxWidth : 800,
          maxHeight    : 600,
          fitToView    : false,
          width        : 'auto',
          height       : 'auto',
          autoSize : true,
          openEffect   : 'none',
          closeEffect  : 'none',           
          ajax: {
            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
               grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
                   sitekey: [RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY],
                   callback: function(response) {
                       console.log(response);
                   }           
               });
           }
         }
       });
    });
    </script>
   ```

Comment: Or you could just use `afterLoad` callback to render recaptcha.